# Remote access to mySql from sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I can connect to SQL instance on remote server through

```
mysql -h ServerIP -u root -p dbNamE
```

But as soon as I try to connect via Sqoop using the command:

```
sqoop list-tables --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect jdbc:mysql://IP:port/dbName --username userName --password password
```

it throws this error:

```
16/05/06 16:46:46 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'IP' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'IP' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4101)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1300)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2337)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.listTables(SqlManager.java:520)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Could not retrieve tables list from server
16/05/06 16:46:46 ERROR tool.ListTablesTool: manager.listTables() returned null
```

Can I get some clarification on this?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify if your connection username is correct, e.g, if you can connect to mysql directly using "-u root", then when connecting with sqoop you should use the same value for the username.

Otherwise, I've got a similar message when I didn't configure the username and password in the hive-site.xml file : it tries then to use a default password (this file can be found in your hive installation folder/conf).

If this is your case, then just configure these properties in that file:

```
<property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>userName</value>
      <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>password</value>
      <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
   </property>
```